# ReSharper rename (Ctrl + R + R) feature stopped working in Visual Studio without triggering any errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper

In Visual Studio 2017 ReSharper rename command brings up the correct ReSharper rename interface. Upon clicking next, the loading bar appears as expected, however after the process is finished the name remains unchanged in all files without any indication that exception occured. Restarting Visual Studio does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refreshing ReSharper cache and then restarting the Visual Studio fixed the issue.

Resharper => Options => Clear caches

[image: Screenshot]

It is a ReSharper bug, most likely triggered by switching solutions.
More info on the [resharper support website](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546989-ReSharper-stopped-working-for-a-single-specific-solution)